# POST file upload, Invalid JSON payload

Tags: node.js, rest, https, google-api, androidpublisher

I am trying to upload a bundle with the [android publisher api of google](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.bundles/upload) using Node.js :

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const bundle_path = ...
const package = ...
const editID = ...
const token = ...

const options = {
  hostname: 'androidpublisher.googleapis.com',
  port: 443,
  path: `/androidpublisher/v3/applications/${package}/edits/${editID}/bundles/`,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Length': fs.statSync(bundle_path).size
  }
};

https.request(options, res => {
  let chunks = [];
  res.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
  res.on('end', () => console.log(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString()));
})
.end(fs.readFileSync(bundle_path));
```

But its returning an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\nPK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0000\u0000\b\u0000\u000eOTR%\n^",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I can't find what is missing in my Node.js code.

Comment: where did you get the token?

Comment: ok where's the code for that?  you followed this to right? https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#using_a_service_account

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests

Comment: wrong link I updated with the good one

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just being stupid, the path was `/upload/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/edits/{editId}/bundles` I had forgotten `/upload` at the start...